# Can't find "Resources" file in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, resx

I'm newbe in WPF. 
I need to add reference on the resources file resx and get strings from it.

```
<Window x:Class="SelectObjectsWindow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:res="clr-namespace:SelectObjectsWindow.Properties"

    Title="{x:Static res:Resources.Res1}" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    ....
</Grid>
```

I got an error: The name "Resources" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SelectObjectsWindow.Properties".
I was searching information about this and find couple of advises:
Set "public" access modifier of resx file.
Change Build Action property of resx on "Embedded Resource".

So, I did it, but nothing changed.
I checked all namespaces. Seems to be ok.
I don't know, what else I should try.

In .cs i can do this without error

```
  var res = Properties.Resources.Res1;
```

Do somebody know, what is wrong?

Comment: If its set to Public, it seems like a Compiler false positiv. Does it compile? if not the problem is not in your Window but elsewere. (the XAML Intellisene/Compiler is some kind of tricky to understand)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Change access modifier from internal to public, your binding will work.[image: Resx file binding to xaml]

Comment: Post your code at dropbox, will look at it. My window shows correct title from resx file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an Assembly reference:

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:SelectObjectsWindow.Properties;assembly=[AssemblyName]"
```

Replace [AssemblyName] with the name of your assembly which can be found by right clicking your project and selecting Properties, go to the Application tab and see Assembly name:

Comment: Make sure the class that the xaml is pointing to is Public, then save and reopen the solution. Could you show the class you are trying to point to as well.