# WPF Windows Form has error accessing resource file only when .xaml code file is open

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I have a .xaml WPF form file.  I am using a .resx file to store the Title of the form.  The pertinent code in the .xaml file looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ProjX.NextGen.Controls.Windows.Workflow.NewOrderWizardWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjX.NextGen.Controls.Windows"
        xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:ProjX.NextGen.Properties"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:ProjX.NextGen.Properties"
        Title="{x:Static resx:StringResources.Windows_NewOrderWizard_Title}"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

When I type the Title line, the intellisense even auto-completes the name of the string resource. However, as long as I have the .xaml file open containing this code, I receive the error messgage `StringResources" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:namespace:ProjX.NextGen.Properties"` I checked the StringResources.resx file and the Access Modifier is set to public.

I also ran the "Run Custom Tool" option on StringResources.resx in order to make sure that wasn't the cause.  I checked the StringResources.Designer.cs file generated and all access modifiers are public and the name spaces match up exactly.

Finally, I checked and the .resx file has properties set to Build Action: Embedded Resource and Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.

What makes this so strange is that if I close the .xaml file the error message goes away and I receive no complication errors.  When I run the project everything acts as normal.  This would not even concern me except that I cannot see or edit the form in the .xaml editing window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, I reviewed all of the answers in this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611419/cant-find-resources-file-in-wpf and none of the suggested solutions solved my issue.

Comment: Did you try to recompile the project while your XAML window is open? Build->Rebuild Solution

Comment: @Isma Yes I have done that several times and the errors are always there after Build and Rebuild unless I close the XAML window.  This happening for all XAML files that reference this StringsResources.resx file.

Comment: May be you can try to delete the intellisense cache: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1

Comment: I tried everything in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1 and nothing worked. I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 and there are no updates that I need to complete. Additionally, I have closed Visual Studio 10+ times and I have rebooted twice with no resolution.